# Best Practice for Exception Handling

Tags: c#, .net

Need know the difference between below two approach in exception handling in side method and also need to know which is the best way to follow

```
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Log error here
                throw new Exception("error message");
            }

            return null;
        }


        public string TestMethod2()
        {
            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Log error here
                throw;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish and what architecture you have

Comment: In the first case you are losing all the stack trace from the original exception. If you've logged it already, that might not be a problem.

Comment: Please at least make an effort to Google. The documentation covers both of these cases specifically which comes up as the first result when searching for `exception handling c#`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx which also come up with numerous other resources going into great detail about best practices for exception handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* is depends on situation, but it's necessary to stress the benefit of the second one:

When you simply use `throw`, *you do not create a new exception*, so on the top of the calling stack if someone handles this exception, he *knows the exact source* of the exception, so can act accordingly.

That is completely different from the first approach, where you are creating a new exception instance, with a new "history".

Comment: I would add that, unless you are in a genuinely trivial situation, you should also always add the original error as an inner exception in the 1st pattern